# proving or disproving a reduction from $R \leq P(Σ^*) \backslash RE$

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, undecidability

I need to prove or disprove that for all languages in $R$ there is a reduction to all languages in $P(Σ^*)\backslash
 RE$. And I'm having trouble to figuring out the solution, especially with dealing with the trivial cases.

Comment: What do you mean by a reduction?  What kind of reduction?  What are your thoughts?  We're not particularly looking for posts that consist solely of the statement of an exercise-style task.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.